# Sonarqube login information not being used by GitLab CI pipeline

Tags: sonarqube, yaml, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, sonarqube-scan

I am running into a problem with generating Sonarqube reports from a GitLab CI pipeline. I think the problem is that the login information I provide is not passed to the pipeline. I did specify it in my yml file:

```
stages:
  - build
  - test
  - sonarqube
build:
  script: "mvn compile"
  stage: build
test:
  dependencies:
    - build
  script: "mvn test"
  stage: test
sonarqube:
  dependencies:
    - test
  script: "mvn compile sonar:sonar -Dsonar.login=admin -Dsonar.password=pass"
  stage: sonarqube
```

When I execute this exact same statement in my IntelliJ terminal, it works and a report is generated. In GitLab, I get the following error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.7.0.1746:sonar (default-cli) on project rlstop: Not authorized. Analyzing this project requires to be authenticated. Please provide the values of the properties sonar.login and sonar.password. -> [Help 1]

Does anybody recognize this issue and know a fix? Thanks in advance

Comment: Try to use sonar authorization token for the admin user. **Click on User Icon (top right hand) >> My Account >> Security >> Generate Token (Give a name to token and click on  Generate)** Add this token in your Gitlab pipeline using `-Dsonar.login=<token>`